# Trying to install kubuntu and need help

Tags: boot, system-installation, kubuntu, acer

Okay, I apologize if there are similar threads... but I've scoured the internet and never have I run across a helpful answer. So I'll ask here...

I have an old laptop, an Acer Aspire 5515... It was running Vista and was taking 5-10 seconds to just do anything, even as simple as opening a folder. So I decided to install a windows-user-friendly version of Linux - something I've wanted to try for a long time. I ended up settling on Kubuntu because I read somewhere that it's medium-light weight, and good for people used to running windows, after all, I can always replace it with something different later on.

I went to the ubuntu site itself and downloaded 
"kubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-am64"

Then the problems started flowing in. Some of it user error I admit... first the CD I got wasn't big enough, then I forgot you can't copy past an iso file, then I couldn't get the Acer to boot from cd drive

Eventually, I fixed these... I burnt the iso image right, used a larger DVD, and changed the bios to boot from the cd. I went to try to just 'try' Kubuntu but that just wasn't working very well, so I just went and tried to go ahead and replace the OS. I knew it would kill everything on the Vista, but I already transferred the files I wanted to keep and the computer was unusable as it was, so I figured why not.

I went through with trying to do the installation, and the first time got to about 80% when I got the `Errno 5 Input/Output Error`

Alright then... it said something about heat so I placed the computer on a low running box fan as a make shift computer fan (It was getting hot anyway), and I tried again. Made it to about the mid-60s and got the same error.

This time, I went and I double checked the iso... it's indeed the most recent one on the Ubuntu site, and then I used winMd5sum, which says the checksum is correct. I then got another disk and downloaded imgBurn and burnt a new disk at the lowest possible speed (tried for 1x, but it did 2x).

Tried again and it still pulled the same error around the same spot.

So this time at the bootup screen I pressed shift and chose Check for Defects, it returned with `Errors found in 1 file` 
The memtest86 says no errors.

So I'm assuming that means there's a problem with the CD/iso? The check sum was supposedly correct and it was burnt on the lowest possible burn with trusted software. Also, the cd drive works just fine and the disk itself is brand new without a scuff on it.

I'm pretty stumped what to do. I'm going to try to find a cheap flash drive at the dollar store or something to try to boot from USB, but if there is any troubleshooting I could do to get this to work without having to spend money I can't really afford, that'd be really helpful.

As it stands I have a nearly 10-year-old computer with no OS whatsoever on it because the windows section is all deleted, but the Ubuntu section is not fully installed.

Answer (score 2):

This type of error can occur when there are too many bad sectors on the hard drive. No matter what, the Ubuntu installer will stop somewhere in the middle until you replace the hard drive. This is easy to check if you have a replacement hard drive handy. Pull out the existing hard drive and try installing Kubuntu again on a different hard drive.

If you are installing Kubuntu, it's recommended that your laptop has about 2GB of RAM or more. If your laptop has only 1GB RAM, you'd be better off installing a more lightweight version such as [Ubuntu MATE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar/518968#518968), Xubuntu or Lubuntu. For a computer with less than 3GB of RAM you should download the 32-bit version.

Comment: I have an external hard drive which functions as my a USB stick essentially. But that's all I have in terms of something like that and I wouldn't know how to format it, or even if it's big enough.

Wouldn't something like that come up in the memtest though? I thought that essentially checked the hard drive, where the check for defects checked the CD (I'm assuming from what I've seen online. Have no prior experience with Linux)

Comment: [memtest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86) is used for testing RAM for errors. I also checked the current price of 2.5" hard drives. A 500GB 2.5" hard drive costs about $50 USD at a brick and mortar computer store. You don't need to format a new hard drive, because the Ubuntu installer will format it for you.

Comment: When I still had an OS on the computer and did the system information check on it, It was reading back to me 3GB of RAM. (with 2.75 Total physical memory, and 5.71 total virtual memory if that matters) So it was supposedly with enough RAM. I'll try to install one of those other ones you mentioned though just to see if it's just Kubuntu that's giving me a problem. This is turning out to be a lot more difficult then I had hoped lol. I was wanting to keep an dying computer usable without having to pour money into it lol

Comment: Ubuntu MATE is user-friendly, Xubuntu is developer-friendly and Lubuntu is like Windows XP without the search dog meme.

Comment: I managed to get the CD to run as a liveCD (Which even that is faster then the computer was acting when it had Vista) So I assume that means the CD isn't the problem. From the live CD desktop of kunubu I'm trying to install once more with a different install option.

Comment: It died installing at 67%
I found I DO have an external drive. The external is pretty old and I use it mostly for backup of files I don't usually bother with but want backed up. I read I can have that partitioned so it keeps the files on it/keep part of it still as storage,and also run the hard drive. How would I go about setting that up? And would I be able to then clear the Linux part when I move on?
Or would it be fine to just run it as a LiveCD, as I'm not making it my main computer?

Comment: I'm not a fan of running Linux on an external hard drive because it runs like a turtle and you have to wait and wait.

Comment: Reusing, keeping "alive" old hardware is commendable but considering that you can buy a new entry level model several generations more capable (and higher resolution screens) than a 10 years old Acer Aspire 5515 for $300 or less... And considering that you can get something out of it selling it on eBay (removed the faulty HDD first, of course) as is... Every other option feels wrong.